# Webforms checkbox choices

Tags: webforms

Is it possible to limit site visitor filling out a webform so that they can only select one of the checkbox and not be able to select any/all checkboxes?

Answer (score 1):

That's called a radio checkbox button I believe. You'll have to do this via javascript to prevent users from selecting more than one option if you cant find a radio checkbox option. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37002599/only-one-checkbox-checked-at-a-time-in-javascript